# delete class item dynamically

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework

in my ionic project I'm using a toggle the generated html of this toggle is:

```
<div class="item-toggle toggle-large ng-valid ng-empty item item-toggle" id="dd" ng-class="checkarrivee.ficheDeMission==undefined ? 'item' : ''" ng-model="checkarrivee.boo[var.id]" ng-click="checkarrivee.isMissionSelected(var.id,checkarrivee.ficheDeMission.id)" toggle-class="toggle-positive"><div ng-transclude=""><span class="ng-binding">Ceintures De Sécurités Passagères</span></div><label class="toggle toggle-positive disable-user-behavior"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkarrivee.boo[var.id]" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty"><div class="track"><div class="handle"></div></div></label></div>
```

is there a way to check item class dynamically, because I don't want the item class to appear in my div, I tried to use ng-class but it didn't work, how I can get div without item class?

Comment: If you want to conditionally render a class, then remove it from your `class=""` attribute and then place it in `ng-class="{'item' : ifTrueRenderItem}"`

Comment: i cant remove it generated by the toggle...tis is the problem

Comment: i want to remove the item from the class generated by the toggle..that what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code is added via directive, you can make another directive to fix this issue. Here is an example (untested, but simple). Is checks toggle-class attribute to trigger an item class check:

```
app.directive('toggleClass', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            if (element.hasClass('item')) {
                element.removeClass('item');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you ser for the answer ..but how i can use it in my code..help ser pleasee?

Comment: you just need to add this directive to your app module as any other directives and it'll do the stuff itself. For example your app is initiated with module like this: var app = angular.module('myApp', []); In this case, you need just to copy this directive to the same file, where var app is declared (right after any configs, in the end of file for sure).

Comment: you are a life saver ser...thank you very much..you are welcome in Morocco in time you want hhh